# Rails How to Generate a Google Drive-like permalink?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When we share a Google Drive Form, it will give our a public url.

How can we implement this in our Rails application? It should be random and not repeated.

Could anyone help me? Thanks.

**Update**

I mean like this url :

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1PPVIMrDo61Er9tqYlJRntfNT73jpxtd_YJGGjXOMlAw/edit?usp=drive_web

But I want a url like this form:

http://yourhost.com/1PPVIMrDo61Er9tqYlJRntfNT73jpxtd_YJGGjXOMlAw

Comment: write an example url so people know the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a `permalink` field to the model whose show action URL you want to share. Really you could use just `/model/:id` but if you want to use `/model/:permalink` then just add the new field, generate the permalink with something like `SecureRandom` and save it to the model, then build the URL and share it.

You could do something like this:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :generate_permalink

  private

  def generate_permalink
    self.permalink = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(32)
  end
end
```

Then in some view where your user can find the permalink url:

```
<%= link_to "Title of the model", some_model_url(some_model.permalink) %>
```

The above helper would create a URL that goes to the show action of your `some_model` controller. You could, of course, create a new action if you wanted and add it to your routes, but I'm just going the simpler way.

In your controller's show action you'd need to find the model by its permalink:

```
class SomeModelController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @some_model = SomeModel.where("id = :id OR permalink = :id", id: params[:id]).first
  end
end
```

With a bit more tweaking in your routes and view, you can shorten the URL to what you posted in your question:

```
http://yourhost.com/1PPVIMrDo61Er9tqYlJRntfNT73jpxtd_YJGGjXOMlAw
```

For this to work, you'd have to add a route to the bottom of your `routes` file so that when no other route is matched, your permalink route will catch the random string and dispatch it to the controller of your choice:

```
# config/routes.rb
get "/:permalink", to: "some_model#show", as: :permalink
```

Here the param will be called `params[:permalink]` rather than `params[:id]` in your controller. You could simplify the code in your controller by making the route `get "/:id"` but I think it's good to be explicit.

Then, just change your view to output the correct URL:

```
<%= link_to "Title of the model", permalink_url(some_model.permalink) %>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: May I ask you a question? Railscast has this : http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url-revised?view=asciicast   I can't understand why it write 'before_validation' instead of 'before_save'.

Comment: If the validations were dependent on the generated slug, then it makes sense to generate the slug before its validated